# How to get Facebook canvas application analytics for events?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas

I am developing Facebook Canvas Application using Ruby on Rails (Ruby-2.2.4), and also I have used JS SDK for login, using that can I be able to get the events analytics?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Animantrn/" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="300" data-height="400" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/Animantrn/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Animantrn/">XYZ Tech</a></blockquote></div>
```

Do you want this kind of page integration to web page?

Comment: No not for the page, but i need to get how many users are using app,how many searches and clicks happened something like that.